# Iterating over methods in interface golang

Tags: go, reflection

I am trying to iterate over all methods in an interface. I have found a few examples - but I can't seem to get mine to work. I am trying to do so with an encapsulated struct that I am using in other packages - but for this case - it is within the same package.

I am trying to iterate over all of the get functions (in my example I have only one - but in real life I have several

I want my output to be two lines

- "2009/11/10 23:00:00 getTenantUUIDQueryInString"
- "2009/11/10 23:00:00 (tenant_uuid IN (UUID_TO_BIN('8df030a1-a057-4f53-a011-a2b1cff673a1'),UUID_TO-BIN('9df030a1-a057-4f53-a011-a2b1cff673a1'))"

Instead, I get the first line and then panic

- "2009/11/10 23:00:00 getTenantUUIDQueryInString"
- "panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value"

here is is on go playground https://go.dev/play/p/YsnJ46QnifT

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "strings"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    pipedTenantUUIDs := "8df030a1-a057-4f53-a011-a2b1cff673a1|8df030a1-a057-4f53-a011-a2b1cff673a1"
    so, responseCode, err := createTenantSearch(pipedTenantUUIDs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err, responseCode)
    }

    t := reflect.TypeOf(&so).Elem()
    v := reflect.ValueOf(&so)

    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {

        method := t.Method(i)
        if strings.HasPrefix(method.Name, "get") {
            log.Println(method.Name)
            whereVal := v.MethodByName(method.Name).Call(nil)
            log.Println(whereVal[0])
        }
    }

}

// I want my output to be two lines
//  "2009/11/10 23:00:00 getTenantUUIDQueryInString"
//  "2009/11/10 23:00:00 (tenant_uuid IN (UUID_TO_BIN('8df030a1-a057-4f53-a011-a2b1cff673a1'),UUID_TO-BIN('9df030a1-a057-4f53-a011-a2b1cff673a1'))"
//
// instead i get a the first line and then panic
// "2009/11/10 23:00:00 getTenantUUIDQueryInString"
// "panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value"
// this is how i have everything set up

type iTenantSearch interface {
    mapTenantUUID(pipedString string) error
    getTenantUUIDQueryInString() string
}

type tenantSearch struct {
    tenantUUID []uuid.UUID
}

func (ts *tenantSearch) mapTenantUUID(pipedString string) error {
    splitString := strings.Split(pipedString, "|")

    for i := 0; i < len(splitString); i++ {
        parsedUUID, err := uuid.Parse(splitString[i])
        if err != nil {
            ts.tenantUUID = []uuid.UUID{}
            return fmt.Errorf("tenant uuid failed to parse: %s", err)
        }
        ts.tenantUUID = append(ts.tenantUUID, parsedUUID)
    }
    return nil
}

func (ts *tenantSearch) getTenantUUIDQueryInString() string {
    inString := ""
    if ts.tenantUUID != nil {
        inString = inString + `(tenant_uuid IN (`
        for i, s := range ts.tenantUUID {
            if i == (len(ts.tenantUUID) - 1) {
                inString = inString + `UUID_TO_BIN('` + s.String() + `')`
            } else {
                inString = inString + `UUID_TO_BIN('` + s.String() + `'),`
            }
        }
        inString = inString + `))`
    }
    return inString
}

func createTenantSearch(tenantUUIDs string) (iTenantSearch, int, error) {
    var tso tenantSearch

    if tenantUUIDs != "" {
        err := tso.mapTenantUUID(tenantUUIDs)
        return nil, 400, err
    }
    return &tso, 200, nil
}
```

Comment: The call `v.MethodByName(method.Name)` returns a zero value because the type `*iTenantSearch` does not have any methods.  Fix by setting `v` to a `iTenantSearch`: `v := reflect.ValueOf(&so).Elem()`.  There are probably other issues, but it's difficult to debug further without a [mcve].

Comment: OK - i made a minimum reproduceable example and edited this question. I tried what you said - it did not work.

Comment: (1) Fix `main` as described in my first comment. (2) The program panics because `createTenantSearch` returns nil. I don't know enough about your application to suggest a fix for this problem.  (3) [Export](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the methods  called with the reflect API.   https://go.dev/play/p/GUzANvcQs3c

Comment: found it!!! - I had an issue with my logic in createTenantSearch  which caused it to return a nil - I feel silly now but thank you so much for the assist. I am getting my arms around reflection in go and this helped me immensely!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to Cerise Limón.. here is the corrected code...

1. fixed logic in create function
2. exported my get method
3. Set v to an iTenantSearch: v := reflect.ValueOf(&so).Elem() –
   Cerise Limón

here is the working code on https://go.dev/play/p/7fG9FcIr6vQ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "strings"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    pipedTenantUUIDs := "8df030a1-a057-4f53-a011-a2b1cff673a1|8df030a1-a057-4f53-a011-a2b1cff673a1"
    so, responseCode, err := createTenantSearch(pipedTenantUUIDs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err, responseCode)
    }

    t := reflect.TypeOf(&so).Elem()
    v := reflect.ValueOf(&so).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {

        method := t.Method(i)
        if strings.HasPrefix(method.Name, "Get") {
            log.Println(method.Name)
            whereVal := v.MethodByName(method.Name).Call(nil)
            log.Println(whereVal[0])
        }
    }

}

type iTenantSearch interface {
    mapTenantUUID(pipedString string) error
    GetTenantUUIDQueryInString() string
}

type tenantSearch struct {
    tenantUUID []uuid.UUID
}

func (ts *tenantSearch) mapTenantUUID(pipedString string) error {
    splitString := strings.Split(pipedString, "|")

    for i := 0; i < len(splitString); i++ {
        parsedUUID, err := uuid.Parse(splitString[i])
        if err != nil {
            ts.tenantUUID = []uuid.UUID{}
            return fmt.Errorf("tenant uuid failed to parse: %s", err)
        }
        ts.tenantUUID = append(ts.tenantUUID, parsedUUID)
    }
    return nil
}

func (ts *tenantSearch) GetTenantUUIDQueryInString() string {
    inString := ""
    if ts.tenantUUID != nil {
        inString = inString + `(tenant_uuid IN (`
        for i, s := range ts.tenantUUID {
            if i == (len(ts.tenantUUID) - 1) {
                inString = inString + `UUID_TO_BIN('` + s.String() + `')`
            } else {
                inString = inString + `UUID_TO_BIN('` + s.String() + `'),`
            }
        }
        inString = inString + `))`
    }
    return inString
}

func createTenantSearch(tenantUUIDs string) (iTenantSearch, int, error) {
    var tso tenantSearch

    err := tso.mapTenantUUID(tenantUUIDs)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 400, err
    }
    return &tso, 200, nil
}
```